# Какой шаблон использовать для рефакторинга сокетного соединения с сервером?

Tags: c#, ооп, сервер, сокеты

Есть игра, в нем реализовано сокетное соединение с сервером.

Запросы на сервер у меня отсылаются прямо с места, где произошло какое-либо событие. Запросы поэтому разбросаны в разных файлах проекта. После частичного ревью, мне сказали, что прямо из файла "Игрок" отправлять запрос на сервер не очень хорошо , а правильнее, наверно с одного места. Подскажите, шаблон, решение или список возможных решений по взаимодействию с сервером.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Подозреваю, в вашем случае хорошо будут смотреться [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, то, что советуют выше - практически тоже самое, что уже происходит в Вашей собственной реализации. Это всего лишь абстрактная обертка для обращений к серверу. Предлагается реализация через архитектурный костыль. Не должно быть обращений к серверу через шеред инстанс-синглтоны и статики! Описанный путь не предлагает должной изоляции. Нормальным решением будет:

1. Создать класс модели, которая может изменяться от событий в сети и/или ввода игрока через публичные методы. В этом классе обращаться к инстансу сетевого соединения и слушать его, для синхронизации данных. Соединение можно хранить в том же GameController, только не делать его расшеренным синглтоном или статиком, а обеспечить доступ по ссылке, через нормально выстроенную архитектуру.
2. Диспетчить события из монобеха в медиатор-класс, и уже оттуда  изменять состояние модели. Эти изменения модель будет синхронизировать с сетью и оповещать медиаторы об изменениях.
3. Сетевые события применять к модели и слать, внутренние события об изменениях (такие же как и в случае изменений от ввода). Медиатор будет ловить их и передавать в монобех.
   Советую посмотреть как разделение полномочий решается в существующих архитектурных фреймворках, например PureMVC.

Answer (score 2):

Эм. У нас в играх, к примеру, есть всегда класс `GameManager`, который управляет и редиректит логику.

Скажем, для отправки запросов, мы создаём `RequestManager`, который реализует `IRequestManager`. В простейшем виде:

```
public interface IRequestManager{
   void Send(string name, Object data);
}

public class RequestManager : IRequestManager{
   [...]
   // отправка запроса
   public void Send(string name, Object data){
       // здесь отправляем запрос
   }
}
```

А у `GameManager` метод по получению ссылочки:

```
public interface IGameManager{
     IRequestManager GetRequestManager();
}

public class GameManager : IGameManager{

   // инициализируете где-нибудь
   IRequestManager mRequestManager;

   // например тут
   public void InitRequestManager(){
      mRequestManager = new RequestManager();
   }

   public IRequestManager GetRequestManager(){
      return mRequestManager ;
   }
}
```

Теперь, если вам надо отправить запрос, то вызываете метод `GetRequestManager` у `GameManager` и отправляете запрос.

`GameManager` можно сделать синглтоном, как-то так:

```
public class GameManager : IGameManager{
   private statc IGameManager mSelf;    

   // инициализируете где-нибудь
   private IRequestManager mRequestManager;

   // например тут
   public void InitRequestManager(){
      mRequestManager = new RequestManager();
   }

   public IRequestManager GetRequestManager(){
      return mRequestManager ;
   }

   public statc IGameManager GetInstance(){
       if(mSelf == null){
          mSelf = new GameManager();
          mSelf.InitRequestManager();
       }

       return mSelf;
   }
}
```

Тогда из любого места программы можно будет отправить запрос так:

```
GameManager.GetInstance().GetRequestManager().Send()
```